# ORA-12545 in batch file

Tags: oracle, tns

I have an Oracle 12.2.01 installed on Windows 2008 server. Whenever I try to connect a batch file using `sqlplus sys/password@master as sysdba @E:/script.sql` I get

`ORA-12545:Connect failed because target host or object does not exist.`

I can ping, tnsping and connect through sqlplus using the exact same syntax.

If I remove the "@master" the script will work. I need to figure out why because some of our scripts will need to use "@master" at customer locations.

Listener file:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = MASTER)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (SID_NAME = MASTER)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = WIN-VFT0F2BL0T6)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.10.82)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

> ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\log
```

SQLNET file:

```
# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: c:\oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

# SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)


SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=8
```

tnsnames file:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

MASTER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.10.82)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = MASTER)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Is WIN-VFT0F2BL0T6 the name of your machine?

Comment: Yes that is the name of the machine.

Comment: I've also tried 0.0.0.0 in the listener and I've had the hostname in the tnsnames.

Comment: The firewall is also off.